# Can not create app using create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, npm, command-line-interface, create-react-app

When I try to create an app using **create-react-app** that give an error

> error eslint@5.6.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this
>   module. Expected version "^6.14.0 || ^8.10.0 || >=9.10.0".
>
> error Found incompatible module info Visit
>   https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this
>   command.

My **node** version is **8.9.3**

My **NPM** version is **6.4.1**

My **create-react-app** version is **1.5.2**

The project cannot create given error are display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update** your nodejs version from https://nodejs.org/en/

Comment: You accepted your own answer? Wow. Lol

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue because my node package wasn't up-to-date. I got this error message:

```
error eslint@6.3.0: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^8.10.0 || ^10.13.0 || >=11.10.1". Got "11.10.0"
```

After some Googling around I stumbled upon this...
https://www.surrealcms.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-or-downgrade-nodejs-using-npm.html

And found that my solution was to use this **npm** command to update the latest stable version of node.

```
sudo n stable
```

A Voilà!

Answer (score 4):

The problem is clearly due to incompatible node version.

Install a program called n that will let you switch between Node versions.

```
sudo npm install -g n
```

Update to the latest stable version of Node.

```
sudo n stable
```

Now use create-react-app

```
npm install create-react-app

create-react-app myapp
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, you need to update your version of Node

To do that, please run: `npm install npm@latest -g`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this cms:

```
yarn config set ignore-engines true
```

Comment: Can you add details about how the proposed command addresses the problem? Code-only answers are not very helpful, neither for the asked, nor others.