# create-react-app not working even when I update node

Tags: node.js, npm, create-react-app

I am trying to run create-react-app and keep getting an error about updating my node version:

```
The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^8.10.0 || ^10.13.0 || >=11.10.1". Got "11.10.0"
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52912509/can-not-create-app-using-create-react-app) post and tried using `sudo n stable`. The output was:

```
installed : v12.14.0 to /usr/local/bin/node
active : v11.10.0 at /Users/Kristin/.nvm/versions/node/v11.10.0/bin/node
```

I am noting here that the version I have installed is 12.14.0 but 11.1.0 is the one being used. Could that be the issue?

After that, I did the following:

```
npm install create-react-app -g

create-react-app myappname
```

I was unable to install create-react-app due to this error:

```
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Kristin/flatiron/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Kristin/flatiron/package.json'
npm WARN flatiron No description
npm WARN flatiron No repository field.
npm WARN flatiron No README data
npm WARN flatiron No license field.
```

Is it possible that I am still running the incorrect version of node or is there something else going on here?

Thank you in advance for your time and advice!

Comment: npm install create-react-app -g
you need to install create-react-app with the flag -g which means install the package globally

Comment: @MuhammadZia I did that and then ran `create-react-app myappname` and still got this error `The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^8.10.0 || ^10.13.0 || >=11.10.1". Got "11.10.0"`

Comment: it's obvious the nodeJs version that you have installed is not compatible with cra. Try installing the latest stable version from this [link](https://nodejs.org/en/)

Comment: I did that already. When I ran `sudo n stable` this was the output. `installed : v12.14.0 to /usr/local/bin/node
active : v11.10.0 at /Users/Kristin/.nvm/versions/node/v11.10.0/bin/node` Is there an issue with the installed v active?

Comment: you need to uninstall everything even nodeJs and install it again. I know it kind of sounds silly but many problems are solved this way, simply just uninstalling and installing things again

Comment: Ok, so `npm uninstall node -g` and then `npm install node -g`?

Comment: no, how did you install npm the first time ?

Comment: npm comes pre-packaged with node > 5.6 I think, u don't need to install it manually

Comment: checkout this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650169/uninstall-node-js-using-linux-command-line) for guide on how to uninstall node and npm completly

Answer (score 1):

try

```
npx -p node@<input_desired_version_here> -- npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript
```

found here https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9614

Answer (score 0):

try to install create-react-app globally with:
npm install -g create-react-app

Comment: I did that and then ran `create-react-app myappname` and still got this error `The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^8.10.0 || ^10.13.0 || >=11.10.1". Got "11.10.0"`

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting what you already have with npm uninstall -g create-react-app, then globally install npm install -g create-react-app.
You can read the documentation at https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/

Comment: Thank you @wellington. I went there and used npx, npm, and yarn and have still not resolve the issue.